# looking for the error for Expected an identifier in one line

Tags: flutter

the error Expected an identifier is on the `?` part, I dont know whats wrong with it.

```
Obx( () => controller.count ==.0. ? Text("Cart is Empty") : Text("${controller.total}")),
```

Comment: I don't know that language but `==.0.` looks very odd

Comment: someone suggested this line, it's supposed to be dart language. im clueless myself